# How to store SQL query result in a local variable of batch file?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, batch-file

I am using following SQL query to get version number from database through a batchfile.

```
sqlcmd.exe -S localhost -d MyDB 
           -Q "set nocount on;Declare @VersionNumber nvarchar(128) set @VersionNumber = (select top 1 versionnumbe from Table_schemaversion order by Id desc)  print 'Your Previous Version is: ' + @VersionNumber "
```

This query is working fine, and producing the correct result.

But now I need to store this result into a local variable of the batch file. And I cannot use any external file here, I have to do this by the query written above, only.

How can I do this? Can anybody let me me about a solution to do this?

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: you are executing this via command line ?

Comment: yes i am executing by command line

Comment: why dont that batch file read the version from an external file instead ?

Comment: i know it is possible by external file, but i have to do this without using any external file, ??? is it possible ??

Comment: Cant you execute the query in the batch file and use the result

Comment: yes i have to do same , but how ? please mention code here ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the command result is a single line this will be enough:

```
FOR /F "usebackq" %%S IN (`sqlcmd.exe -S localhost -d MyDB  -Q "set nocount on;Declare @VersionNumber nvarchar^(128^) set @VersionNumber = ^(select top 1 versionnumbe from Table_schemaversion order by Id desc^)  print 'Your Previous Version is: ' + @VersionNumber "`) DO SET var=%%S
```

or

```
FOR /F  %%S IN ('sqlcmd.exe -S localhost -d MyDB  -Q "set nocount on;Declare @VersionNumber nvarchar^(128^) set @VersionNumber = ^(select top 1 versionnumbe from Table_schemaversion order by Id desc^)  print ^'Your Previous Version is: ^' + @VersionNumber "') DO SET var=%%S
```

Comment: i applied both the above commands but not able to print its result. I need to store its output in a variable, like set a = myversion number,

Comment: is there any error?Did you tried to print the var after that- > `echo %var%`

Comment: looks like a stuff printed by sqlcmd.exe.Is the new line mandatory?You can set a new line in `FOR /F` condition without harming the loop.

Answer (score 4):

You will have to write the result of query in a temp file and then read it from there.

```
sqlcmd  -S ".\SQLEXPRESS" -Q "select c1 from [a].[dbo].[t1] where c1='1'" -U sa -P wavetec -h -1 -o tempstorage.txt        
set /p varname=<tempstorage.txt
echo %varname%
```

- -o: creates the file
- -h -1: omits the header

Hope this is what you want!!